# Is there a Vim plugin similar to Git History Diff?

Tags: git

I like the extension [Git History Diff](https://github.com/huizhougit/githd) in Visual Studio Code, looks something like this:

[image: Git History Diff]

I am looking for something similar for Vim.
I've looked at Fugitive and other Vim plugins, but they are awkward when compared to Git History Diff.

Does anyone know of a Vim plugin similar to Git History Diff?

Comment: With `futigive`, you have the `:Gllog` command to populate your location list with the commit history. You can then navigate it with `:lprevious` and `:lnext` (which you can map to, say, `[l` and `]l`), showing a buffer with inline-diffs for each commit. This make it quite easy to see changes. But what are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: I would love it if I could just click on a line and it shows me who edited that line last. Just like VS Code with Git History Diff.

Comment: Then, to be sure, have you tried `:Gblame`?

Answer (score 2):

How about [git-blame](https://github.com/zivyangll/git-blame.vim)
which puts the message in the status line?

Comment: It's not exactly what I am looking for, but it might be good enough.